# How to show html file with css in local server

Tags: node.js, webserver

When I run my HTML file on a local server written in node.js, the CSS file that I linked in my HMTL file does not work.

my javascript code

```
const http=require('http');
const fs=require('fs');
http.createServer(function(req,res){
    fs.readFile("index.html",(error,data)=>{
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        return res.end();
    })

}).listen(8080);
```

my HTML file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css href="./css/desktop.css">
    <title>CODESTER-TrackYourProgress</title>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

my CSS file is in folder css, and name is called `desktop.css`.

Comment: have you tried fs.readFile('./index.html', ... ) ??

Comment: Your webserver responds to *every request* with the contents of the HTML file. You have not written any code that does anything else than that, so that's the only thing that is happening. You need to look at the `req` variable and serve different files to the browser depending on what the request contains.

Answer (score 1):

Express module solved the problem
you can use

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('folder containing your static files'));
//statics files are css,photos etc
```

Comment: This code resolves my issue thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
const http=require('http');
const fs=require('fs');
http.createServer(function(req,res){
    const { method, url } = req;
    const surl = new URL(url, 'url the server is running on');
    if (method == 'GET' && surl.pathname == '/index.html') {
        fs.readFile("index.html",(error,data)=>{
            res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
            res.write(data);
            return res.end();
        })
    }
    if (method == 'GET' && surl.pathname == '/css/desktop.css') {
        fs.readFile("/path/to/css/desktop.css",(error,data)=>{
            res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/css'});
            res.write(data);
            return res.end();
        })
    }

}).listen(8080);
```

Be sure to replace `/path/to/css/desktop.css` with your actual path to the file and `'url the server is running on'` with a valid url that the server is running on eg. `http://127.0.0.1/`

Comment: this code thrown a reference error

Comment: ReferenceError: method is not defined

Comment: @Vivek Edited: Should work now